# Pytorch - vanilla Gradient Visualization

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, visualization

I trained a neural network on MNIST using PyTorch:

```py
class MnistCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d( 1, 16, 3, stride = 1, padding = 2)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, 3, stride = 1, padding = 2)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size = 2)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.lin = nn.Linear(32 * 8 * 8, 10)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # conv block
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        # conv block
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool2(x)
        # dense block
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.dropout(x)
        return self.lin(x)
```

I would like to implement vanilla Gradient Visualization (see reference below) on my model.

```
Simonyan, K., Vedaldi, A., Zisserman, A.
Deep inside convolutional networks: Visualising image classification models and saliency maps.
arXiv preprint arXiv:1312.6034 (2013)
```

**Question: How can I implement this method in PyTorch?**

If I understand correctly, *vanilla gradient visualization* consists in computing the partial derivatives of the loss of my model w.r.t all the pixels in my input image. So to make it short, I need to tweek my `self.conv1` layer so that it computes the gradient over its input pixels instead of the gradient over its weights.

*Please correct me if I'm wrong.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to change anything about your conv layer. Each layer computes gradients *both* w.r.t. parameters (for updates) *and* w.r.t. inputs (for "downstream" gradients by the chain rule). Therefore, all you need is to set your input image's `x` gradient property to true:

```py
x, y = ... # get one image from MNIST
x.requires_grad_(True)  # indicate to pytorch that you would like to look at these gradients
pred = model(x)
loss = criterion(pred, y)
loss.backward()  # propagate gradients
x.grad  # <- here you should have the gradients of the loss w.r.t pixels
```